# Does casting heap storage from const to non-const invokes undefined behavior?

Tags: c, malloc, constants, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Standard says:

> (6.7.3) If an attempt is made to modify an object
>   defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with
>   non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

And in undefined behaviour section:

> An attempt is made to modify an object defined with
>   a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with
>   non-const-qualified type (6.7.3)

The return value of **malloc** is a block of **uninitialized storage**. No **object** has been constructed within that storage.

That said, is the code below legal?

```
#include
#include

typedef struct {
    unsigned char h;
    const unsigned int v;
} liber_primus;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    unsigned int lykilord;

    if (!(argc - 1))
        return 0;

    liber_primus *runaljod = malloc(sizeof (*runaljod));

    if (!runaljod)
        abort();

    runaljod->h = *(unsigned char *)argv[1];
    *(unsigned int *)&runaljod->v = 3307U;

    lykilord = runaljod->h * runaljod->v;

    free(runaljod);

    return lykilord;
}
```

Comment: it's not legal because you use `unsigned int *` instead of `unsigned long *` for the accesss :)

Comment: Apart from that, there's no object **defined** with a const-qualified type here, so at least your citations give no reason why this should be illegal. But maybe the rules around *effective types* would have something to say about that ... I think it's fair to add a language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @FelixPalmen forgot to change 'v' from ulong to uint.

Comment: The `v` field is indeed attempted to get modified as stated in your citation, so that paragraph does apply to it. The effective type at the time of assignment is `const`-qualified object. OTOH it will likely to "work" most of the times.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't think **that** paragraph applies. There's no **definition** of an object in that code. The object returned by `malloc()` gets an *effective type* through the first write to it, but that's a different story.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Hm.. yeah. Could be a loophole :)